# I am creating an event to identify the Member Status

Tags: discord, discord.js

```
client.on('raw', async dados => {
  if(dados.t == 'PRESENCE_UPDATE' && this.client.guilds.cache.get("948835296089342012").members.cache.get(dados.d.user.id)){
    let membro = this.client.guilds.cache.get("948835296089342012").members.cache.get(dados.d.user.id)

    if(dados.d.activites.state == null) return membro.roles.remove("653651520361070612")
    if(dados.d.activities.state == undefined) return membro.roles.remove("653651520361070612")

    let valor = dados.d.activities.state.toLowerCase()
    let n = valor.search(`discord.gg/server`)
    
    if(n>=0) membro.roles.add("653651520361070612")
    if(n<0 && membro.roles.cache.has("653651520361070612")) membro.roles.remove("653651520361070612")

  }
```

log=

```
user: { id: '932194344859996180' },
  status: 'online',
  guild_id: '947899731303096320',
  client_status: { web: 'online' },
  activities: [
    {
      type: 4,
      state: 'aa536a43',
      name: 'Custom Status',
      id: 'custom',
      created_at: 1647655901662
    }
  ]
}
```

I'm creating an event to identify the member's Status, for example: if the member has the url in the discord.gg/3 status the member will receive a position and when he removes the status the bot will remove the selected position

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The presence is only available on [GuildMember](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/discord.js/stable/class/GuildMember) not an user. Get the member who used the command from [`message.member`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/discord.js/stable/class/Message?scrollTo=member) (make sure that the command is used in a guild)
Now read the member's presence through [`message.member.presence`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/discord.js/stable/class/GuildMember?scrollTo=presence). Seems like you are trying to get member's custom status. It's one of [`presence.activities`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/discord.js/stable/class/Presence?scrollTo=activities) array and has the type [`Activity`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/discord.js/stable/class/Activity). Find in that array which has the type is `CUSTOM`, that is what you need. Note that presence can be null so you need to check if it exists.
This is the code I have tested and it works. Hope it works for you too:

```js
const member = message.member; // Get member from message
const custom = member.presence?.activities?.find(x => x?.type === 'CUSTOM'); // Get the custom status from member's presence
if (custom?.includes('cat') console.log('This user has `cat` in his/her custom status');
else { console.log('This user doesn\'t have `cat` in his/her custom status'); }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const Command = require("../../structures/Command");


module.exports = class teste extends Command {
  constructor(client) {
    super(client);
    this.client = client;

    this.name = "teste";
    this.category = "Fun";
    this.description = ".";
    this.usage = "";
    this.aliases = [];

    this.enabled = true;
    this.guildOnly = true;
  }
  async run({ message, args}, t) {

  const user = 
    this.client.users.cache.get(args[0]) ||
      message.mentions.members.first() ||
      message.author

  console.log(user.presence.activities.state)

}
}
```

I also tried to use this without being on the basis of the Event but on the command, it always returns undefined

log=

```
[
  Activity {
    id: 'custom',
    type: 'CUSTOM',
    url: null,
    details: null,
    state: 'aa536a43',
    applicationId: null,
    syncId: null,
    platform: null,
    party: null,
    assets: null,
    flags: ActivityFlags { bitfield: 0 },
    emoji: null,
    sessionId: null,
    buttons: [],
    createdTimestamp: 1647656752595
  }
]
```